# Undefined method 'login_at' with Sorcery and 0auth, rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, sorcery

I'm trying to set up Oauth with this rails project, but everytime I click 'login with ...' in my view, it renders an undefined method error for 'login_at'. My Sorcery config file contains the specific external submodule

`Rails.application.config.sorcery.submodules = [:remember_me, :external]`

but I still can't get past that error, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You also have to provide external providers to sorcery config, e.g.

```
Rails.application.config.sorcery.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.external_providers = [:twitter, :facebook]
  ...
end
```